# What is wrong with this c code with a pointer to struct with pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code? And why I'm getting the compilation error? And how to solve this issue?

```
struct recPtr_t{
int * l;
int * w;
};
typedef struct recPtr_t recPtr;

recPtr r1 = {0,0};
recPtr * rPtr1 = &r1;
printf("Default dimensions of rectangle are %d and %d\n", rPtr1->l, rPtr1->w);
```

The warning:

```
rectangle.c:28:59: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
printf("Default dimensions of rectangle are %d and %d\n", (int *)rPtr1->l, (int *)rPtr1->w);
                                            ~~            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rectangle.c:28:76: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
printf("Default dimensions of rectangle are %d and %d\n", (int *)rPtr1->l, (int *)rPtr1->w);
                                                   ~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: "what is wrong with this code?" - the error message is telling you: "format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'"

Comment: Why are l and w int*?  Shouldn't they be just int?

Comment: Yes you're right @cup.  No need for pointers inside the struct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You define the struct to hold (int *) but when initializing the struct you pass in integers. That’s the problem. It’s just a warning so the compiler is letting you know what you have done. It will take the 0 to be the value of the (int *) which will cause problems later on.

Comment: Thanks. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you should change your struct to contain **integers** instead of **integer pointers**.

you should have:

```
struct recPtr_t{
int l;
int w;
};
```

this will solve your issue.